# How to create a kubernetes namespace in an idempotent way with AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

How can I create a k8s namespace manifest in an idempotent way or ignore the error if the namespace already exist with AWS CDK.

If I create a K8s namespace with a manifest, I regularly get errors that the namespace already exists:

`from custom resource. Message returned: Error: b'Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "/tmp/manifest.yaml": namespaces "dev-advanced" already exists\n`

Create Manifest:

```py
    def create_namespace(self) -> KubernetesManifest:
        m = self.cluster.add_manifest(
            f"ns_{self.tenant.name}",
            {
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "kind": "Namespace",
                "metadata": {
                    "name": f"{self.tenant.name}",
                    "labels": {
                        "name": f"{self.tenant.name}"
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        return m
```

Comment: Hm, you can probably make the add!anifest conditional, but I am not sure if this is a good idea, if your run no longer adds the manifest it will be removed from CF… it’s probably better to maintain such global objects in a stack which you only run once?